# MouseEventArgs .handled equivalent? Click AND mouseup firing twice

Tags: c#, event-handling

Is there an equivalent for MouseEventArgs to doing e.Handled? I'm having a problem where my event handler is firing twice on the same object. I click the object (a button), it runs through the code which is supposed to delete the button. I step through, step by step, as it deleted the button. But then it runs through again! I check the sender- its the (supposedly deleted!) button 0_o.

```
    private void InTrayButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        int element = 0;

        //Find the index of the button in the list
        foreach (ButtonList a in buttonList)
        {
            if (button == a.buttonSaved)
                break;
            element++;
        }

        //Remove the button
        this.Controls.Remove(buttonList[element].buttonSaved);
        buttonList[element].buttonSaved.Dispose();
        buttonList.Remove(buttonList[element]);

    }
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I might force it to stop going off twice? It doesn't matter whether I set this as a mouseup or a click event, it fires off twice every time >_>

Comment: Events are multicast; are you sure you have not wired up more than one handler (or even the same handler in your situation) more than once?

Comment: I think that just trying to hide the fact that the handler is being called twice is the wrong mentality. Its getting called twice for a reason, better for you to track down the cause of that.

Comment: That answered my question! Sure enough, I was adding the event handler in a place that did end up getting called more than once. Thank you very much! If you place that as an answer, then in 10 minutes when it lets me I will select that!

Comment: Jesse- you're absolutely right. I was overlooking the reason for about 30 minutes and had hit the "I don't care, I just want to make it work!" point. I'm glad it worked out this time, but next time I'll do better about focusing on the cause rather than a workaround!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are wiring up the same event handler more than once in your code. I recommend tracking down where that is and making sure it occurs only once.